# [GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$taskId" of required type "String!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql

```
<button
 onClick={ () =>
  updateTaskStatus({
   variables: {
    taskId: budgetData.taskId,
    status:
     currentRole === "owner" && "Open"
   }
  })
 }
>
 Post
</button>
```

I get that this happens when the value is undefined or null but my issue here is whenever I restart the server and click on the button it works fine but when I try to do it again it doesn't work anymore and I get this error.

Comment: check network request .. what is really passed

Comment: Could you please explain a little more about this ? @xadm ?

Comment: browser tools, network tab, `POST /graphql` details

Comment: `"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"` - This was there in the network tab. and also I can see this error message in console `[Network error]: ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 400`

Comment: request, not response